# opening MS word document without using com object

Tags: php

Hai frnd can give me some solution..
1.how to open ms word document without using com(word.application)
2.actually i want to edit existing document only changing content without affecting any properties?

Answer (score 0):

[Zend_Service_LiveDOCX](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.service.livedocx.html) is a solution that doesn't require COM.  It uses a web service.

See this [PHP tutorial](http://www.phplivedocx.org/articles/brief-introduction-to-phplivedocx/).

Comment: sorry i dint get any code and idea regarding zend service including can u give some coding exaple

Comment: actually i wannt to write some content to exisisting document...without using com object
suppost if u go file ->propertis->summaru/custom some content will be there if i edit that document na that properties getting erase

Comment: i want to open that document without using com object and write into that document without using com object

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/documentation). It is .NET port of the [POI](http://poi.apache.org/) library. I used it for excel but guess should work for word as well.

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't much help because you need a solution now:
[PHPWord](http://phpword.codeplex.com) currently only writes and only to .docx files. It is still in the early stages of development, but is worth keeping an eye on, and readers will be forthcoming in due course, as will support for .doc.