# opening a word document in php (.doc)

Tags: php, view, ms-word, .doc

I want to open a .doc file and print out using php (or only count lines and words). I tried with the COM library, but it didn't work (I'm using linux server). I also tried installing `Antiword` but it doesn't work, because in my server `safe_mode=off` and i can't change it.
Are there any solution, how can I open and view this file or simple count how many lines or words does it have?

Comment: If it's a word '07 .docx file, then it's just a bunch of XML you can read using PHP's dom. For the old school OLE-based files, then you're probably SOL. Even MS can't read them properly. Some reasons why here: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/02/19.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading DOC file in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358637/reading-doc-file-in-php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opening a MS Word Document without using COM object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902154/opening-ms-word-document-without-using-com-object)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=open+word+document+php

Comment: @Gordon: +1 for making me laugh with that last one...

Comment: Okey, i saw every possible question that looks like mine, and as i said i need to open or count the lines from a .doc file (not .docX, which can be find in the answers above) . Thanks @Marc B for the explanation

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading/writing a MS word file in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188452/reading-writing-a-ms-word-file-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Install `catdoc` on your server and use `shell_exec` to invoke it. With the converted plain text you can do your word and line counts.